# Rounding numbers in a Python Label Expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, labeling, arcgis-pro

I'm having trouble rounding a percentage number using a label expression in Python. Just displaying the label as shown below is fine.

```
def FindLabel ( [Deaths], [PercentageDead] ):
    if ([Deaths]) == "0":
        return [Deaths]
    else:
        return [Deaths] + "\n" + [PercentageDead] + "%"
```

I tried implementing the example given on [Arcgis online](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/specify-text-for-labels.htm) but as soon as I try to round off the extra digits in my percentage all of those features go blank on my map. No label is displayed whatsoever for those feature.

```
def FindLabel ( [Deaths], [PercentageDead] ):
    if ([Deaths]) == "0":
        return [Deaths]
    else:
        P = round(float([PercentageDead]), 5)
        return [Deaths] + "\n" + P + "%"
```

I've tried converting to a float or an int, and than converting it back to a string but nothing seems to work. If I try to manipulate that field whatsoever the expression will return nothing.

I just want to round off the digits to 5, how would I do that? I'd be willing to switch to Arcade if it would yield the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `P` variable is a number and you're attempting to use the `+` operator with a number and strings.  You cannot do this.  You can `+` two strings or two numbers, but not a string and a number.

There are a few alternatives that you could try.  My preference is to use the string `format()` function to do variable interpolation.  It will convert numbers to strings on the fly.

Eg:  `return "{}\n{}%".format([Deaths], P)`

This also has the advantage that it will not fail, even if there is a NULL (`None`) value, or some other unexpected data type.  It will even convert that to a string, so at least you can see where the problem might be.

**UPDATE (to address your comment):**

The behaviour you've described in your comment is consistent with being unable to convert the string to a float (eg, because it has non-numeric characters in it).

You could wrap this in a `try:` block to test it, something like:

```py
try:
    pDead = float([PercentageDead])
except:
    return "{}\nFAILED to convert '{}' to float!!!".format([Deaths], [PercentageDead])

P = round(float(pDead), 5)
return "{}\n{}%".format([Deaths], P)
```

Comment: As it turns out the error might be coming from the `P` declaration. Wherever I put it the code will stop executing at that exact line. Putting it at the top results in all labels being blank. Any ideas?

Comment: What field type is your `PercentageDead` field?  Is there any chance it is a string type that includes a `%` symbol?  The behaviour you've described is consistent with being unable to convert the string to a float because it has non-numeric characters in it.

Comment: I had actually fiddled with the field type and forgot about it, setting it back to numeric makes it all work great! If I did set the field type back to percentage, how would I ignore the `%` character when rounding it?

Comment: In a string you can replace instances of a substring `"%"` with an empty string, `""`,  like:  `float( [PercentageDead].replace("%", "") )`